# No output displayed when a pointer is defined;

Tags: c++, eclipse, pointers, console

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int val = 8;
    int *point = &val;
    cout << val << *point << endl;
}
```

I wrote a fairly straightforward program to print out the value of a variable first by using the variable name then by using a pointer to the variable. For some unknown reason though, no output is printed to the console.

However, if I run the same code line by line in the debugger, I get the expected output (88).

Since this problem is likely specific to me, I'll add that I'm using Eclipse Kepler with the MinGW compiler on a 64 bit system. Any help on how I can solve this problem and get pointers to function normally would be highly appreicated.

Comment: First, you forgot a return.  If you add a cin.ignore, do you see the output?

Answer (score 1):

I found your answer [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/197552/)

and since your code and debugger is correct - this is what you the post recommends that you do:

```
[1] Uninstall
- Removed all traces of Eclipse (64-bit).
- Removed all traces of MinGW (and/or Cygwin).
- Removed all traces of Java (SDK and JRE).

[2] Restart PC

[3] Install
- Installed latest Java JDK (includes the JRE) 32-bit.
- Installed Eclipse IDE (Java Edition) 32-bit.
- Installed MinGW (with Msys).
- Installed the necessary CDT tools from within Eclipse.
```

However, as an avid Xcode/Jetbrains user I would recommend that you check your settings first because those are the funnest to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Should work this way:

- add stdafx.h
- return 0 at termination